# JavaScript object variable undefined at run-time, but is accessible

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've encountered a little bit of strange behavior with JavaScript whilst trying to get access to an object variable that does exist but not at run-time.

The following shows the initiation of the object which I'm trying to access:

```
app.examView = new app.ExamView({el: $("#main_wrap"), model: model});
```

Here is the definition and the call to the object creation where I'm trying to get access to the app.examView variable.

```
app.ExamView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){  
        this.render();  
        this.calculatorView = new app.ExamCalculatorView({el: $("#exam_calculator_container"), model: this.model});   
        this.questionView = new app.ExamQuestionView({el: $("#exam_question"), model: this.model});
```

Logging the examView variable here returns undefined:

```
var app = app || {};

app.ExamQuestionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        console.log(app.examView);
```

Although, the object is accessible via the console: 
[image: Firebug console]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the code that was responsible was:

```
app.ExamAnswerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() { 
        ...
    },
```

app.examView will not be accessible until initialize has finished executing.

Using a timeout to wait until the function has finished executing, solved the problem.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    app.examView.calculatorView.refresh();
}, 100);
```

Using a delay isn't preferred, but it's now giving access to the variable.

Seems using promises would be handy here!

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume that your Backbone View is getting it's `render()` called before DOM is ready. Is your code wrapped in `$(document).ready()`?

The "strange behavior" is because the element becomes available after the DOM has been finalized.

Comment: Yes, the code was wrapped in `$(function () { ... });`.